# Escape format with number_to_currency

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, view-helpers

I have a weird situation, i'm using `number_to_currency` helper from `ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper`. The snippet of code using this:

```
.price
  .value= number_to_currency price, format: "%u<b>%n</b>", precision: 0
```

When I'm running this project locally, it works as it should be:

**$500** (only numbers are bold)

But when I'm deploying that to stage server, it gives me:

```
$<b>500</b>
```

I'm not sure what kind of problem is this, i've tried to precompile assets but didn't help. Also tried `html_safe` with no success.

Any idea how to resolve this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, may be it will work..

`.price
 .value= number_to_currency 100, format: "%u<b>%n</b>".html_safe, precision: 0`